# use i tag in @Html.ActionLink

Tags: html, asp.net

I want to use same HTML design in my ASP .Net MVC application

```
<li>
  <a href"#">
    <i class="fa fa-cog"></i>
    "Account Settings"
  </a>
</li>
```

This must show the settings icon and "Account Settings" in same line but using this in ASP.Net shows the icon and text in different lines

```
<li>
    <i class="fa fa-cog">
    </i> 
          @Html.ActionLink("Account Settings", "Index", "Manage", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
</li>
```

i need help that to use this  tag with @Html.ActionLink function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible with an ActionLink.

You could use URL.Action instead like so.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Manage")"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i> Account Settings</a>
```

Or just use a standard link

```
<a href="~/manage"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i> Account Settings</a>
```